# Data sets for predicting home value

Tags: data-request, web-crawling, big-data, real-estate

I'm working on a project for predicting the cost of houses. I'm looking for data sets enumerating the number of schools, hospitals, parks and any other condition that may affect the price of houses (e.g., crime rate). Ideally, the data set should include zip codes information. Can anyone point me to a good resource for this?

I'm looking for recent data, not more than 5 years ago, would be great if it's already organized but if not I can scrape, just need to know where it is.

Comment: The appraisal used for taxes is not exactly selling price but there is lot of public data available.   And I think you mean selling price.  The cost of a new house is the land plus the cost to build it.   Include flood plane and taxes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is an opendata stack exchange site for questions like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably going to need to get information from many jurisdictions - at least in the US, there is not a good/granular sources for property tax, crime, and other information for all states in one dataset.

- For **crime data**, check out FBI UCR reports which are usually not granular. Each city may (hopefully) report their own data. Try google and/or http://opendatanetwork.com (a search engine for open data)**.

  - You will find crime data on many open data sites such as data.cityofchicago.org and data.boston.gov
- For **hospital and school data**, national datasets may suffice.

  - You can find CMS/Medicare certified hospitals (most in the US) in a list at 
    https://data.medicare.gov/Hospital-Compare/Hospital-General-Information/xubh-q36u
  - https://nces.ed.gov should have school-level location data for you as well.

I would also suggest checking out aggregators like Trulia.com, Zillow.com, and WalkScore.com. They all have APIs if I remember correctly but with limits on access as well as data use.

** I help run this site at work (Socrata.com)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for data like this

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Housing

Comment: That looks useful except for the fact that is from **July 7 1993** and the poster is looking for data from within the last 5 years.

Answer (score 1):

Zillow has a free API that will return their estimate of average home prices. You can get the data down to zipcode and neighborhood level.

http://www.zillow.com/howto/api/APIOverview.htm