# Historical and Current Houses Listed for Sale within Price Ranges

Tags: data.gov

I am need of finding data for housing prices in aggregate values such as; 
Homes listed for sale or sold - 0 - 100k, 100 - 200k, 200 - 300k, etc. for a given time period, like as of 12/31/2012.

I need this data in order to determine the availability of homes for sale for certain income levels within certain metropolitan statistical areas, I have searched the FHFA website but could not locate anything other than HPI and median household price for the given areas.

So in essence I would need;

In Metropolitan Statistical Area (41740 - San Diego, for example) 
As of 12/31/2015:

X amount of homes for sale between 0 - 100k

Y amount of homes for sale between 100 - 200k

Z amount of homes for sale between 200 - 300k

etc.

Comment: you may want to look at http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6780/data-sets-for-predicting-home-value and http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/7635/us-house-sale-data -- if these don't help, explaining how your request is different will help in soliciting answers.